# What does < (less-than sign) between a function identifier and a function parameter mean?

Tags: c++

```
struct point {
    int x, y;
    bool operator<(const point &p) {
    if (x == p.x) return y < p.y;
    else return x < p.x; 
    } 
};
```

What does < between operator and (const point &p) signify?

Comment: It's the part of the function name. If you haven't learned about operator overloading, I would start there.

Comment: It's not between anything. The name of the method being defined is `operator<`.

Comment: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What does `<` between operator and `(const point &p)` signify?

It's a part of the member function name. It is a definition of a member function which is an overload of the `<` operator. It is what makes this work:

```cpp
point a{};
point b{};

if(a < b) { // point::operator<(const point&) is used here.
    // 
}
```

Note: The member function should really be `const` qualified because calling the function does not change `*this` (the lefthand side of `<`).

```cpp
bool operator<(const point &p) const {
//                             ^^^^^
```

---

... and it's also preferable if it's not even a member function, but a free function (taking two `const point&`):

```cpp
bool operator<(const point& lhs, const point &rhs) {
    return std::tie(lhs.x, lhs.y) < std::tie(rhs.x, rhs.y);
}
```

This is because if `point` has an implicit conversion constructor, it will allow an instance of a type that is implicitly convertible to `point` to appear on both the lefthand and righthand side of `<`.
Example:

```cpp
struct point {
    point(int X, int Y) :x{X}, y{Y} {}
    point(const std::pair<int, int>& pair) : x{pair.first}, y{pair.second} {}

    int x, y;
};

bool operator<(const point& lhs, const point &rhs) {
    return std::tie(lhs.x, lhs.y) < std::tie(rhs.x, rhs.y);
} 

int main() {
    std::pair<int, int> ip{10,20};
    point pnt{10,19};

    // This works with operator< as a member function or a free function:
    if(pnt < ip) std::cout << "pnt < ip\n";

    // This will not work if `operator<` is a member function:
    if(ip < pnt) std::cout << "ip < pnt\n";
//     ^^
// implicitly converted to `point`
}
```

Comment: @NeilButterworth Sidequestion (if you don't mind): What has happened with your SO account? Where has all your rep gone? It says _"Member since 5 months"_ and the only answer it shows that you've provided was back in 2011. It doesn't add up :-)

Comment: Possibly the same that happened to my previous two accounts.  I changed email (because I changed jobs), and had to start new accounts.  I smartened up on my current account, and use my own personal email instead of my work email.  (And lost all my previous accrued rep.  Boo hoo, alligator tears.  Oh well.)

Comment: @Eljay Ahhh... So one can't change email address on SO? :-( It's odd that it shows a post from Neil from 2011 and _"member since 5 months"_ though.

Comment: I think you can change email on SO, but you either need to plan ahead (... I didn't plan ahead), or you need to get tech support involved to fix the account (... I didn't bother tech support).  The "2011" on Neil's account is odd.  Does Neil have two accounts, and happened to login to an old mostly unused account?

Comment: @ted i decided i didn't want to be active on so and that i didn't like a lot of my posts, so i  got jeff to remove my posts, at great effort (things may be easier now). these days i am bed-ridden, and feel the urge to make the odd comment, to keep me amused! some things might not have got cleaned up.

Comment: @NeilButterworth ❤️

Comment: @NeilButterworth ❤️